# How do I stop a certain script in Next.js from loading in any 404 or 410 pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I don't want some or all of these scripts to not load in any pages that return a 404 or a 410

The code in `_document.js` is

```js
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: React.Children.toArray([initialProps.styles]),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {CssBaseline.flush()}
          
          {/* Below This  */}
          
        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-************"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     
          {/* Above This */}
          
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't want this script

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.jsclient=capub************"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

to load in 404 and 410 pages

Comment: In this case, instead of _document.js, you need to add it to every page you want to load it on.

Comment: Doing that loads the script twice in a single page and adsense doesn't like that

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a parent layout component for children components (pages) in which you want to insert this script. After this step, this script is unnecessary in the _document.js after that the default pages (e.g. error pages) do not render this script.

Comment: That also inserts the script twice in the head tag

Comment: I think you did something wrong. If you remove this script from _document.js and add it to the parent layout it should not appear twice in the output.

Comment: Nah any async script is being injected in the head twice

Comment: It appears once if it's not an async ```script``` tag for async it appears twice